# NgIf not working with observable

Tags: angular, observable, angular-ng-if

I'm  having a bit of an issue with getting an observable to be picked up by ngIf. I have two components and  I'm trying to get one component to cause the other component to show or not show content.

## filterComponent.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import{Observable } from "rxjs";
    import {FilterDataService} from "./filter-data.service";
    import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-filter',
       templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']   
     })
    export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
      show: boolean;
       constructor(private filterData: FilterDataService) { }

       ngOnInit() {

         this.filterData.currentSource.subscribe(show => this.show =show);
         this.changeShowFlag(true);
       console.log('Filter Show is ' + this.show);

      }

       changeShowFlag(showFlag:boolean) {
         this.filterData.changeSource(showFlag);
         console.log("current show value " + showFlag);
         console.log("value of show confirmed as "+ this.show);
         console.log("value in service for source " +  this.filterData.source);
          }
         }
```

## filterComponent.html

```
     <p>
           filter works!
    </p>
     <div class ="toggles">
     <div class="toggle-border">
        <input [(ngModel)]="show"  
          (click)="changeShowFlag(!show);" type="checkbox" id="one" />
        <label for="one">
          <div class="artHandle"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

## filterDataService.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";


     @Injectable()
     export class FilterDataService {
       private _Source = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
       public source:boolean = true;
       currentSource = this._Source.asObservable();
      constructor() { }

      changeSource(sourceFlag: boolean) {
       this._Source.next(sourceFlag);
       this.source = sourceFlag;
      }


    }
```

## consumerComponet.ts

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
     import { FilterDataService} from "../filter/filter-data.service";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-consumer',
      templateUrl: './consumer.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./consumer.component.css']   
    })
    export class ConsumerComponent implements OnInit {
       source: boolean;
       constructor(private filterData: FilterDataService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.filterData.currentSource.subscribe(source  => this.source  = source   );
     }

    }
```

## consumerComponent.html

```
     <p>
        consumer works!
     </p>

     <div *ngIf="source" >
       show  is on
     </div>
```

## app.modules.ts

```
     import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
     import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

     import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
     import { FilterComponent } from './filter/filter.component';
     import { ConsumerComponent } from './consumer/consumer.component';
     import {FilterDataService} from "./filter/filter-data.service";
     import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

     @NgModule({
       declarations: [
         AppComponent,
         FilterComponent,
         ConsumerComponent
      ],
       imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
      ], 
      providers: [FilterDataService],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
      export class AppModule { }
```

## app.component.html

```
      <div>
        <app-filter></app-filter>
     </div>
     <div>
         <app-consumer></app-consumer>
    </div>
```

Now if i click on the slider the value is changed and a get a  console output as expect to tell me the value has changed but for some reason the consumer component using  ngif does not toggle on and off. As i would have expected it to do. I'm sure i'm missing something and its probably a very easy fix but i've been searching for a week for a solution and thought i'd post this question. To see if anyone can advice where i'm going wrong.  Thanks in advance for any advice and help.

Comment: You could try building a plunker that we could work with. Or you could try adding more log statements (such as in the consumer) and see if you can determine where the problem resides.

Comment: where da ngIf with observable ?

Comment: Your code works fine [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SjhNK4flB53I2bB8ywDh).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the async pipe:

```
source$: Observable<boolean>;
constructor(private filterData: FilterDataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.source$ = this.filterData.currentSource;
}


<div *ngIf="source$ | async" >
    show  is on
</div>
```

There are a few reasons, one is it's cleaner and handles asynchronous operations for you.  The second is that your component as it stands actually has a memory leak in it because you don't unsubscribe, the async pipe cleans those up for you.

Will also recommend that you remove this:

```
public source:boolean = true;
```

from your service.  That is state, and it is a source of bugs and is unneccessary. consumers of this service should always use the observable. You will encounter headaches if you get into a habit of mixing synchronous and asynchronous operations like this.

Answer (score 0):

try async pipe like this :

```
export class ConsumerComponent implements OnInit {
   source: Observable<boolean>;
   constructor(private filterData: FilterDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.source = this.filterData.currentSource;
 }
```

and you use it that way in the view

```
<div *ngIf="source | async" >
   show  is on
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone I actually only posted sample code I  found my actual error I had included the service provider in the components as well as  app.modules.
I've added the async pipe as suggested but then it all stops working again. So I've removed it.